# How to have shortcode autofilling the content if the attribution is specified?

Tags: shortcode

I want to have a shortcode that can fill the content depending on the value of its argument. Here is my code:

```php
function test( $attr, $content ){
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
            'content' => 'Not loading',
        ), $attr );
    if ( $args['content'] == 'foo' ) { $content = 'bar' ;}
    return 'A' . $content . 'B';
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test' );
```

Here is how it does:

| Input | Expected output | Actual output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[test content="foo" ]` | `AbarB` | `AbarB` |
| `[test]blabla[/test]` | `AblablaB` | nothing |
| `[test]` or `[test][/test]` | `ANot loadingB` | `AB` |

Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two could happen if you **mixed *self-closing and enclosing shortcodes* for the same tag/shortcode**, e.g. you put the shortcodes in question into the same post content like so:

```html
1) Self-closing: [test content="foo" ] and 2) Enclosing: [test]blabla[/test]
```

.. in which case WordPress' shortcode parser would treat those two shortcodes as only *one* shortcode, i.e. it begins at `[test content="foo" ]` and ends at the `[/test]`, whereby the `$content` value would be  `and 2) Enclosing: [test]blabla`.

So try creating a brand new post and *add only one* of the above shortcodes, e.g. **just the** `[test]blabla[/test]`, and then you'd get the expected output, i.e. `AblablaB`.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes for more details.

And if you want to use your shortcode in both the self-closing and enclosing forms, then you can avoid the parsing issue by using `/` as in `[test /]` (or `[test/]`), which functions just like the `/` in self-closing HTML tags like `<br />`, `<hr />`, `<img ... />`, etc.

So for example, (note the `/]`)

```html
1) Self-closing: [test content="foo" /] and 2) Enclosing: [test]blabla[/test]
```

.. and with that, you'd get the correct output — `1) Self-closing: AbarB and 2) Enclosing: AblablaB`.

---

As for the `[test /]` (or just `[test]` when not mixed with the enclosing form), or `[test][/test]` (the enclosing form), the correct output based on your code is actually `AB` and *not* `ANot loadingB`.

Because the shortcode was used without any content where "content" here refers to the content in between the opening and closing tags, e.g. `[test]this is the CONTENT[/test]`.

And secondly, the shortcodes didn't have the `content` *attribute/parameter* (e.g. as in `[test content="foo"]`), hence the `$content` remained empty, which then outputs `AB`.

So if you actually wanted `Not loading` to always be the `$content` value when the content and `content` attribute are both empty or not specified, then you could do something like..

```php
$content = $content ? $content : 'Not loading'; // add this line
return 'A' . $content . 'B';
```

That way, `[test /]` and `[test][/test]` would give you `ANot loadingB`.

Comment: PS: Sorry, I wanted to type "self-closing", but ended up with "self-enclosing".. hence I revised my answer and corrected the typo.